Real vector version of Cauchy's Integral Formula
On the Wikipedia page for Cauchy's Integral Formula there is a statement of a generalisation of the formula to real algebras, stated in terms of geometric algebra as
$$
f(\mathbf {r} )=-{\frac {1}{i_{n}}}\oint _{\partial V}{\frac {\mathbf {r} -\mathbf {r} '}{S_{n}\left|\mathbf {r} -\mathbf {r} '\right|^{n}}}\;d\mathbf {S} \;f\left(\mathbf {r} '\right)
$$
where $S_n$ is the volume of the unit $n$-ball and $i_n$ is the pseudoscalar. As someone unfamiliar with geometric algebra, would it be possible for someone to translate this into standard vector terminology, in particular for the case where $f$ is a 2D or 3D vector (i.e. $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2 $ or $f: \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$)? My application is to find a diffeomorphism between the interiors of two 2D (or 3D) shapes where I know a relationship between the boundaries of the shapes.
This similar question has comments that are probably helpful for someone a bit more familiar with this topic.

Neither you nor the Wikipedia article say what $V$ is. Could you clarify this?

$V$ is the volume (I believe assumed to be simply connected) being integrated over, with boundary $\partial V$

(It needs to be noted that the Wikipedia articles derivation is incorrect. $\nabla'$ does not have a product rule in the way they claim. The correct product rule is quite different. They happen to arrive at the correct result anyway.)
Monogenic Functions
This is only true for (left) monogenic functions $\nabla f = 0$ where $\nabla f$ is the vector derivative (the geometric product of $\nabla$ with $f$, with $\nabla$ acting on $f$). This condition is equivalent to
$$
  0 = \nabla f = \nabla\cdot f + \nabla\wedge f \iff \nabla\cdot f = 0 = \nabla\wedge f.
$$
The term $\nabla\wedge f$ is called the curl of $f$, and in 2D and 3D is equivalent to the usual notions of curl. In higher dimensions, we can write the zero curl condition in components as
$$
  \partial_if_j - \partial_jf_i = 0
$$
for all $i,j$. In other words, being monogenic is equivalent to the Jacobian of $f$ being symmetric and trace-free.
Cauchy's Formula for Non-monogenic Functions
For non-monogenic functions there is an additional term over the bulk involving $\nabla f$:
$$
  f(\mathbf r) = \frac1{S_ni_n}\oint_{\partial V}\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}d\mathbf S\,f(\mathbf r') - \frac1{S_n}\int_V\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}dV\,\nabla f(\mathbf r').
$$
(I apologize if I've gotten any signs wrong, it gets quite confusing.) $dV$ is the usual scalar volume element. I've used $\mathbf r'-\mathbf r = -(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')$ as the former quantity makes more geometric sense: $\mathbf r$ is the "center" we're evaluating at, and $\mathbf r'-\mathbf r$ is the vector based at that center pointing at the point $\mathbf r'\in\partial V$.
From here on I will denote the boundary term by $f_\partial$ and the bulk term by $f_\bullet$, more precisely
$$
  f_\partial(\mathbf r) = \frac1{S_ni_n}\oint_{\partial V}\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}d\mathbf S\,f(\mathbf r'),\quad
  f_\bullet(\mathbf r) = \frac1{S_n}\int_V\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}dV\,\nabla f(\mathbf r').
$$
It is perhaps worth noting that $f_\partial = f + f_\bullet$ is monogenic, so we can think of $f_\partial$ as the monogenic portion of $f$ and $f_\bullet$ as the non-monogenic portion.
In General
The Boundary Term
Let $s(\mathbf r)$ be the $(n-1)$-vector tangent to $\partial V$ at $\mathbf r$ so that
$$
  d\mathbf S = s\,dS,\quad i_n = \mathbf ns,
$$
where $\mathbf n(\mathbf r)$ is the outward pointing normal. This convention is implicit in the above form of the generalized Cauchy formula. Note that
$$
  i_n^{-1}s = (-1)^{n-1}si_n^{-1} = (-1)^{n-1}\mathbf n^{-1} = (-1)^{n-1}\mathbf n
$$
and that $i_n\mathbf v = (-1)^{n-1}\mathbf vi_n$ for any vector $v$. Then
$$
  f_\partial(\mathbf r) = \oint_{\partial V}\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{S_n|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\mathbf n(\mathbf r')f(\mathbf r')\,dS.
$$
Because the result must be a vector, we can write
$$
  f_\partial(\mathbf r)
  = \frac{1}{S_n}\oint_{\partial V}\left[\left(\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\cdot\mathbf n(\mathbf r')\right)f(\mathbf r')
    + \frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|^n}\bigl(\mathbf n(\mathbf r')\cdot f(\mathbf r')\bigr)
    - \left(\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\cdot f(\mathbf r')\right)\mathbf n(\mathbf r')\right]\,dS.
$$
It is worth noting that when $V$ is a ball and $\mathbf r$ is its center, $\mathbf r'-\mathbf r=|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|\mathbf n$ and only the first term is left:
$$
  f_\partial(\mathbf r)
  = \frac{1}{S_n}\oint_{\partial V}\frac{f(\mathbf r')\,dS}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^{n-1}}.
$$
The Bulk Term
This is algebraically identical to the boundary term, with $dV$ instead of $dS$ and $\nabla$ instead of $\mathbf n$:
$$
  f_\bullet(\mathbf r)
  = \frac{1}{S_n}\int_{V}\left[\left(\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\cdot\nabla\right)f(\mathbf r')
    + \frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|^n}\bigl(\nabla\cdot f(\mathbf r')\bigr)
    - \left(\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\cdot f(\dot{\mathbf r}')\right)\dot\nabla\right]\,dV.
$$
The last term is not expressible using standard vector calculus notation. The intent is that $\nabla$ is only acting on $f$, not the $\mathbf r'-\mathbf r$ term; this is specified by the overdots. In index notation,
$$
  \left(\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\cdot f(\dot{\mathbf r}')\right)\dot\nabla
  = \sum_{ij}\frac{x_i'-x_i}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}(\partial_jf_i)e_j
$$
where $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ is the standard basis.
2D
The Boundary Term
The above is the general formula. We can make it nicer in 2D and 3D.
In 2D you get exactly Cauchy's formula, treating $f$ as if it were a complex function. Formally, we replace $\mathbf r$ with $z = \mathbf r\mathbf e$, $f$ with $F(z) = f(z\mathbf e)\mathbf e$, and $\mathbf n$ with $N(z)=\mathbf n(z\mathbf e)\mathbf e$, where $\mathbf e$ is a fixed unit vector. Algebraically, $z$ and $F(z)$ are complex numbers; $\mathbf e$ is a choice of real axis. The monogenic condition $\nabla f = 0$ is equivalent to $F$ being holomorphic. In this case $i_2$ is the imaginary unit, and $dz' = d\mathbf S\,\mathbf e = \mathbf ni_n\mathbf e\,dS = -Ni_n\,dS$.
$$
  F_\partial(z)
  = \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\partial V}\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^2}\frac{i_2}{i_2}\mathbf e^2\mathbf n(\mathbf r')\,dS\,f(\mathbf r')\mathbf e
  = \frac{1}{2\pi i_2}\oint_{\partial V}(dz')^*\frac{F(z)}{(z'-z)^*}.
$$
The conjugates comes from the conventions $i_n = \mathbf ns$ and $z=\mathbf r\mathbf e$. Reversing the orders in both yields the traditional Cauchy formula.
The Bulk Term
Because
$$
  x + yi_2 = z = \mathbf r\mathbf e = (x\mathbf e + y\mathbf e_\perp)\mathbf e
$$
we must have $i_2 = \mathbf e_\perp\mathbf e$, where $\mathbf e_\perp$ is the direction of the imaginary axis. We now compute
$$
  \frac{d}{dz'}
  = \frac12\left(\frac\partial{\partial x'} - i_2\frac\partial{\partial y'}\right)
  = \frac12\mathbf e\left(\mathbf e\frac\partial{\partial x'} + \mathbf e_\perp\frac\partial{\partial y'}\right)
  = \frac12\mathbf e\nabla.
$$
Thus we see
$$
  F_\bullet(z)
  = f_\bullet(\mathbf r)\mathbf e
  = \frac1{\pi}\int_V\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^2}dV\,\mathbf e\frac{dF}{dz'}
  = \frac1{\pi}\int_V\frac{dF/dz'}{(z'-z)^*}dV.
$$
This is an area integral over the complex plane.
3D
The Boundary Term
In 3D, we can wrap up the last two terms of the general formula into a cross product,
$$
  f_\partial(\mathbf r)
  = \frac1{4\pi}\oint_{\partial V}\left[f(\mathbf r')\left(\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\cdot\mathbf n(\mathbf r')\right)
    + f(\mathbf r')\times\left(\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\times\mathbf n(\mathbf r')\right)\right]dS,
$$
or the first and last terms,
$$
  f_\partial(\mathbf r)
  = \frac1{4\pi}\oint_{\partial V}\left[\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\bigl(f(\mathbf r')\cdot\mathbf n(\mathbf r')\bigr)
    + \frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\times\bigl(f(\mathbf r')\times\mathbf n(\mathbf r')\bigr)\right]dS.
$$
The Bulk Term
We do the exact same thing to get
$$
  f_\bullet(\mathbf r)
  = \frac1{4\pi}\int_{V}\left[\frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\bigl(\nabla\cdot f(\mathbf r')\bigr)
    - \frac{\mathbf r'-\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|^n}\times\bigl(\nabla\times f(\mathbf r')\bigr)\right]dV.
$$

Many thanks! This is brilliant. I will be calculating these integrals numerically, and would be more confident doing that with real values rather than complex ones: for the 2D case, is there any simplification of the general formula in terms of standard vectors? I can't spot one, but the complex form is so much neater I wondered if something similar can be done with the vectors?

@AnotherShruggingPhysicist No, I don't think there's any simplification. You will just have to use general formula or the 2D complex formula.

Also, I fixed an error in the total, non-monogenic formula; added an alternative form for the 3D case; and added all the corresponding expressions for the bulk term.

Many thanks @Nicholas - this type of answer is why I love stackexchange
